# RSS reader for huge number of feeds

Tags: webapp-rec, rss

I've been using Google Reader for past couple of years, but as the number of feeds grow, it's getting pretty ugly.

I don't really read in GR, I only use it to grab news and I read on the website itself. I can't even organize the feeds in GR, since it's interface clearly wasn't build for high number of feeds.

**Is there any RSS reader that makes it easy to manage couple hundreds of feeds?** Please don't suggest to unsubscribe from 95% which I don't read, since I'm mostly interested in titles than whole article bodies.

Answer (score 1):

[Shaun Inman](http://shauninman.com) created this cool rss reader (I've never used it, but every review I've found says it's really good, and the screen shots look really cool) called [fever](http://feedafever.com). It is a full text reader, however I think you can set it up to just show titles, and it organizes the articles by how much exposure they're getting, so you get the top news up top and the less important news (according to the twitter and a few other sites) lower down.

You could also setup your own system using the Google feed api. It's rather simple, and only shows headlines, but you'd have to create your own page for it and learn the feed api (which is pretty simple, but still, it's something you'd have to learn). If you choose this one you can contact me and I'll help you out if I can.

The last option I've got is to use [Tiny-Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/), which is a self-hosted piece of software which you can infintely customize to suite your own needs (because it's open source), however you'd probably have to get into the code to fix it up exactly as you need it, but again, it could be done, and exactly to your standards.

Comment: The important thing about Fever, which makes it relevant to this question, is that Inman claims that it works **better** the more feeds you have. It is, also, however, a paid app, and a self hosted one at that, so most people probably can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.netvibes.com for all my rss feeds. Lots of options for displaying feeds and you can customise quite a bit in relation to layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain about web based readers but [FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/) is a very powerful reader and also syncs with Google Reader. There are two versions - an ad-supported lite and a more powerful paid-for version.

After some searching, web based feed reader Bloglines which was supposed to have been on the chopping block has now been revived and is available for users.

UPDATE: Bloglines has a teeny-tiny postscript which says "Powered by Netvibes", so see what solution suits you best.